# Python tkinter - Arguing String Input for Entry( )

Tags: python, if-statement, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am learning Python tkinter fundamentals, and cannot get my method called "Submit()" to argue the string value for my Entry1 variable.
I have tried the .get() method for Entry1, but the console says the get attribute does not exist for Entry1.

```
from tkinter import *

Window = Tk()

def Submit():
    Answer = Entry1.text
    if Answer == "byte":
    print("correct")

Label(Window, text="What do you call 8 bits?").grid(row=0)
Entry1 = Entry(Window, text="").grid(row=1)
Button(Window, text="SUBMIT", command=Submit).grid(row=2)

Window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.  Thanks, though.

```
from tkinter import *
Window = Tk()

def Quiz():
   if Answer1.get() == "8" :
       print("correct")

Question1 = Label(Window, text="How many bits are in a     Byte?").grid(row=0)
Answer1 = StringVar()
Entry1 = Entry(Window, textvariable=Answer1).grid(row=1)
Button1 = Button(Window, text="ANSWER", command=Quiz).grid(row=2)

Window.mainloop()
```